# shell script writing to a new file

Tags: file, text, shell

Quick question: If I do the following, will it create the file, or do I have to do that separately?

```
 echo "output" > file.txt
```

Comment: In command it will create a file. Why didn't you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will create it unless you have no right to create a file in the current directory.